# discord.py how to organize help command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I got getting all commands working, but I cant figure out how I can sort them like:

```
Images:
avatar <user> > get someones avatar
etc.
Text:
clap <text> > generate text with clapping emojis
etc.
```

heres what i have right now:

````
@bot.command(usage="test [command]", description="get help")
async def test2(ctx, args=None):
dude = ''
if args is None:
    for i,x in enumerate(bot.commands):
        dude += (f'{PREFIX}{x.usage} » {x.description}\n')
    await ctx.send(f'```{dude}```')
````

I tried making them as groups but then realized i would have to use them with image avatar @peter

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting around the problems by using brief='x_command' as an thing to recognize the commands category

````
@bot.command(usage="test [command]", description="get help")
async def test2(ctx, args=None):
dude = ''
if args is None:
    for i,x in enumerate(bot.commands):
        if x.brief == 'image_command':
            dude += (f'{PREFIX}{x.usage} » {x.description}\n')
    await ctx.send(f'```{dude}```')
````

so the commands look like this

```
@bot.command(brief='image_command',usage="avatar <user>", description="send users avatar to chat")
async def avatar(icy, user:discord.User):
await icy.message.delete()
await icy.send(user.avatar_url)
```